# Load .obj file with original colors without .mtl

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a `.obj` file which is colored (when opened in MeshLab or Microsofts 3D builder) but there is no `.mtl` file associated with it. In ThreeJs I open it using the simplest possible way but it is grey.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('assets/model.obj', (object) => {

  this.scene.add( object );

},);
```

Comment: Working on it... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11422

Answer (score 0):

*OBJ format does not support color data without an MTL file.*

However, some applications do parse the unsupported method of v line RGB data to display color as vertex colors.

The typical format you want to look for in your OBJ file to validate that this is how your obj file is imparting color is:

```
v x y z[w] r g b
```

If this is in fact how your file is imparting color, you may find some hope here: https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/objVertexColors